# Disposing an IRandomAccessStream

Tags: stream, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Is it safe to assume that when the first `then` clause finishes, `bitmapStream` will be disposed because it goes out of scope at that point (thereby making it's ref count go to 0)?

```
BitmapImage^ bmp = ref new BitmapImage();
create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)).then([](StorageFile^ file)
{
    return file->OpenReadAsync();
}).then([bmp](IRandomAccessStream^ bitmapStream)
{
    return bmp->SetSourceAsync(bitmapStream);
}).then([bmp]()
{
    // Do some stuff with bmp here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, `StorageFile::OpenReadAsync()` returns a `IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType>^` which is an asynchronous operation.

This operation creates and holds a reference to the `IRandomAccessStream`, when the operation is done, the PPL tasks get a reference to this stream through [`IAsyncOperation<TResult>::GetResults()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206600.aspx)
and they hold the reference, at least, until the second lambda function is done (the lambda function in the second `then()`).

After that, if the `BitmapImage` holds another reference to the stream, then the stream won't be disposed for a "long" time.

If you would like to dig more into this topic, you may be able to create your own implementation of `IRandomAccessStream` interface and put a breakpoint in the Dispose method.